# ImageJ - Accessing the results log

Tags: macros, imagej

This might be a very simple question, but I am writing a little Macro for ImageJ and I cannot access the values in the Results log. Here is the code that does NOT work:

```
selectWindow("Results");
test=getResult("channel",0);
print("test");
```

Any tips on how this could be done? Thanks.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What error does it give you?

Comment: "Results" table empty in line 6. test=getResult("channel",0<)>;

Comment: I am wondering whether the problem is that the Results table that I am looking at is not the main Results table that ImageJ has. The one that I have comes from the Analyze/Color Histogram...

Comment: The information that you use the [Color Histogram](https://github.com/fiji/Color_Histogram/) plugin is crucial. Info such as this one should better be incorporated into the main question by editing, instead of being in a comment that might even be deleted at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in pointing out that it might be due to a plugin not using the standard results table of ImageJ. The [`Color_Histogram`](https://github.com/fiji/Color_Histogram/) plugin uses a [non-standard way](https://github.com/fiji/Color_Histogram/blob/master/src/main/java/ColorHistogram_.java#L344-354) to report the results.

I filed a [pull request](https://github.com/fiji/Color_Histogram/pull/1) on github.com that fixes this. When this pull request is merged and uploaded to the Fiji updater, the following macro code works as expected after running *Analyze > Color Histogram*:

```bsh
test1 = getResultString("channel", 0);
print(test1);
test2 = getResult("mean", 0);
print(test2);
```